# ¿Como puedo sacar un porcentaje en SQL de un periodo previo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda porque por mas que he tratado de resolverlo solo no he podido pero lo que ocurre es que tengo una base de datos con alumnos y cuantos de ellos aprobaron o reprobaron en cada ciclo y estoy haciendo una tabla en donde de forma porcentual quiero saber si durante este ciclo hubo un aumento de los alumnos aprobados

Este es un ejemplo de como veo la tabla por si me pueden ayudar a conseguirlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo intente con:

```
SELECT Status,
Count DIF (Aprobado) AS Reprobados
```

Comment: No se entiende bien, la tabla que muestras como imagen es la que quieres conseguir supongo, ahora bien ¿De qué manera vas a sacar el porcentaje? En base a 10? Y por qué quieres hacerlo? Sabiendo que si es mayor a 5 (p.ej.) ya está aprobado, por qué hacerlo porcentualmente?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, te dejo un ejemplo, espero te ayude.Las columnas "TotalAlumnos" y "TotalAprobados" son solo informativas, las puedes quitar si lo deseas.

```
select 
    ciclo
    ,count(matricula) as TotalAlumnos
    ,sum(status) as TotalAprobados
    , cast(SUM(status) as decimal(10,2))/cast(COUNT(matricula) as decimal(10,2))*100.0 as [%Aprobados]
from 
(
    select Ciclo,matricula
        ,case when status='Aprobado' then 1 else 0 end as status 
    from #Alumnos
)a
group by ciclo
```